# Can't access DropDownList control from GridView header row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a problem with GridView headers. I can't access a DropDown control from a header, even tho there is one.This is how my grid looks like

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" 
               ID="AcceptedRecordsGridview"
               AutoGenerateColumns="false"
               DataKeyNames="idn" 
               CssClass="table" 
               GridLines="none"
               AllowPaging="true" 
               OnPageIndexChanging="OnPaging" 
               AllowSorting="true"
               PageSize="4" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="idn">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("idn") %>'>
                </asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("idn") %>'>
                </asp:Label>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Message info" SortExpression="ninfo">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ninfo") %>'>
                </asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ninfo") %>'>
                </asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Unit ID" SortExpression="idb">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("idb") %>'>
                </asp:Label>
           </ItemTemplate>
           <EditItemTemplate>
               <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("idb") %>'>
               </asp:Label>
           </EditItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
       <asp:TemplateField>
           <HeaderTemplate>
               Status:
               <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStatus"
                                 runat="server"
                                 OnSelectedIndexChanged = "StatusChanged" 
                                 AutoPostBack = "true"
                                 AppendDataBoundItems = "true" >
                   <asp:ListItem Text = "ALL" Value = "ALL">      
                   </asp:ListItem>
                   <asp:ListItem Text = "Top 10" Value = "10">
                   </asp:ListItem>
               </asp:DropDownList>
           </HeaderTemplate>
           <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("status") %>'>
               </asp:Label>
           </ItemTemplate>
           <EditItemTemplate>
               <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("status") %>'>
               </asp:Label>
           </EditItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Received" SortExpression="time">
           <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("time") %>'>
               </asp:Label>
           </ItemTemplate>
           <EditItemTemplate>
               <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("time") %>'>
               </asp:Label>
           </EditItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Solved" SortExpression="timeUpdated">
           <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("timeUpdated") %>'>
               </asp:Label>
           </ItemTemplate>
           <EditItemTemplate>
               <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("timeUpdated") %>'>
               </asp:Label>
           </EditItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I want to access drop down control from the HeaderTeamplate tag. I tried different solutions, like this one `DropDownList ddlStatus =                 (DropDownList)AcceptedRecordsGridview.HeaderRow.FindControl("ddlStatus");`
also I tried to get the control using **RowDataBound**, and also tried with **foreach** statement to loop through rows but every time I get null reference exception. Can someone please tell what I am doing wrong? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: show you RowDataBound or Foreach Code

Comment: foreach (GridViewRow gr in AcceptedRecordsGridview.Rows)
        {
           DropDownList drop =  gr.FindControl("DropDownList1") as DropDownList;
         
        }
this is how my for each statement looks like

Comment: The `foreach` doesn't work because the header-row is omitted from `GridView.Rows.GetEnumerator`. But it would be interesting to see the `RowDataBound` approach.

Comment: When are you trying to find the control? before loading the grid or after?

Comment: it is after I load the grid and populate it with data from MySql

Comment: @MoMo any error when you tried to find?

Comment: @Bharadwaj as I mentioned in my post, if get NullRefferenceExpression as result

Answer (score 1):

The `foreach` approach doesn't work because `GridView.Rows` never returns the header or footer but just the rows which [`RowType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.rowtype(v=vs.110).aspx) is [`DataRow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datacontrolrowtype(v=vs.110).aspx).

So you have to use `RowDataBound` which is called after the grid is data-bound for each row including the header and footer. So it's necessary  to check the `RowType`:

```
protected void AcceptedRecordsGridview_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        DropDownList ddlStatus = (DropDownList) e.Row.FindControl("ddlStatus");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this one triggered automatically after the grid is populated with data, or I need to trigger it somewhere I need it ?

Comment: @MoMo: it is triggered for **every** row when you call `AcceptedRecordsGridview.DataBind()` after you have assigned the `DataSource`. Or it is triggered automatically if you use an `ObjectDataSource` or `SqlDataSource`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
foreach (GridViewRow gr in AcceptedRecordsGridview.Rows)
{ 
  if (gr.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
  {
   DropDownList drop = gr.FindControl("DropDownList1") as DropDownList; 
  }

}
```

Comment: I tried this one also, but have no idea why it does not enter the loop. I used a break point inside look to check if it runs, but apparently it is skipped